# how to copy files(links) from a column in sheets, to a specific folder in drive?

Tags: file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, directory, copy

I'm trying to, on form submission, copy the files (which appear as links) from google sheets, specifically from column c, only, to a master folder. the links are to the pdfs within a folder, not a folder itself.

I end up with this fail code: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.
copyFilesToMasterFolder @ Code.gs:10

My file id is correct. I don't know what to modify?

```
    function copyFilesToMasterFolder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var fileLinks = sheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();
  var masterFolder = 
DriveApp.getFolderById("1y5ezQEbS0fDr2TcOjum5wOy6xWHHJcy1");

  for (var i = 0; i < fileLinks.length; i++) {
    var fileLink = fileLinks[i][0];
    var fileId = fileLink.split("/")[fileLink.split("/").length - 2];
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    file.makeCopy(masterFolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your scirpt, what value is `fileLink`?

Answer (score 0):

1.In Google Sheets, select "Tools" from the top menu, then select "Script editor".

2.In the Script editor, paste the following code:

```
    function copyFilesFromSheetToDrive() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID");  // Replace with the ID of the target folder
  var column = 1;  // Column number of the links in the sheet
  
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(data[i][column - 1]);
    folder.addFile(file);
  }
}
```

1.Replace "FOLDER_ID" with the ID of the target folder in Google Drive. You can find the ID in the URL of the folder, e.g., "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/FOLDER_ID".

2.Save the script and close the Script editor.

3.Back in Google Sheets, select the script from the "Run" menu, or run it by clicking the play button in the Script editor.

This script will copy all the files linked in the first column (column 1) of the active sheet to the specified folder in Google Drive. You can modify the script to copy files from a different column or from a different sheet by changing the column and sheet variables, respectively.

Comment: I correctly added file location and changed column 1 to 3 and got this code: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.
copyFilesFromSheetToDrive @ Code.gs:8

Comment: function copyFilesFromSheetToDrive() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1y5ezQEbS0fDr2TcOjum5wOy6xWHHJcy1");  
    // Replace with the ID of the target folder
     var column = 3;  // Column number of the links in the sheet
  
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(data[i][column - 3]);
        folder.addFile(file);
      }
    }